# How can I create a route on Strapi?

Tags: routes, relational-database, strapi

I am trying to create a route on Strapi in order to get comments from one article.

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/routes.html#configuring-core-routers

The solution proposes to create a route in an existing file in a routes folder itself in an API folder.

What is the mistake with syntax?

```
'use strict';

/**
 * post router.
 */

const { createCoreRouter } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreRouter('api::post.post', {
    only: ['find'],
    config: {
        find: {
          auth: false,
          policies: [],
          middlewares: [],
        }
    },
    method: "GET",
    path: "/posts/:id/comments",
    handler: "posts.comments"
});
```

Data from the API we can see in my article:

[image: Post data]

Comment: Put everything & only what is needed to ask your question in your post, not just at a link. Relate it to your question. Use text, not images/links, for text [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this code snippet:

```
// path: ./src/api/[apiName]/routes/[routerName].js (e.g './src/api/restaurant/routes/restaurant.js')

const { createCoreRouter } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreRouter('api::post.post', {
  only: ['find', 'findOne'],
  config: {
    find: {
      auth: false,
      policies: [],
      middlewares: [],
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?